# Cannot login to SQL Server 2012 after changing Server Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know this has been asked before but I couldn't find a solution... I had to change a server name for a SQL Server 2012 machine after moving it to a new domain. I was able to log into single user mode and enable SQL Server authentication and add a SQL Server user. I'm able to login that way, but the software that uses the DBs on the server require Windows Authentication.

I've tried running

```
sp_addserver 'Servername', local;
```

The server responds with The server already exists, but I still cannot login with Windows Authentication... please help.

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question. This is more server administration. try the DBA site.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change server name(on instance), after you changed windows server name, you should execute:

```
sp_dropserver <old name>;
go
sp_addserver <new name>, local;
go
```